# Soft for making license keys

Tags: .net

I have almost finished a small application. I found several clients and thought about monetization. I decided to sell licenses. I have never encountered the creation of keys for the program.
**What software for creating license keys do you use?** Or is it better to write the key generator by myself? How do you prefer to do?
Desirable free or low cost solutions.

Comment: Syncfusion has used a combination of a key generation tool and validation assembly that works based on common key. We have provided this to some of our customers for their own products and have plans to publish the code to Github soon. We can share the same with you if are interested.

Comment: Yes, I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 4):

If you feel that you can write a key generation program by yourself, just do it!
There may be ready-made parts of the program, some blanks for generating keys on [GitHub](https://github.com/).
Also, you can try ready-made solutions like [ArmDot](https://www.armdot.com/). They are paid. There are various licensing systems. Specify which programming language do you use and you'll get more good answers.

Comment: There is a .net tag in the question. If you were able to find a .net solution that costs money, shouldn't you be able to add others without knowing if they are looking for vb.net or C#? Also, the GitHub link just takes you to Gist. It's kind of confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the trial version. It looks good, but I would like something free to start.